# Accessing SQL Server 2008 from MonoTouch

Tags: sql-server, xamarin.ios

I am using MonoDevelop and MonoTouch to create an application which needs to access SQL Server 2008 tables. I understand that if you use objective-C then the only way to access SQL Server is via web service but what about MonoTouch. Is there anything better than coding a web service when using MonoTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better?  I would say no there isn't.  Creating a Web Service is the way to go in this scenario.  You keep your data access layer on  the server, you keep your security footprint small, and you enforce data validation on the server-side.  All of this keeps your MonoTouch application smaller and focused on the Presentation layer and Business Logic Layer.

From your question, I am assuming you would rather stay away from WCF but it really is the way to go.  This way you set yourself up to work with MonoDroid, a website, Windows Phone 7, or other platforms without additional Data Access (and possibly Business Logic) layers needing to be written.  Even if my research didn't suggest that there isn't a SQL Server connector for MonoTouch, I would still recommend going with WCF.  From what I have seen though, it doesn't seem like you have a choice here.

Answer (score 1):

I recently attended the Microsoft Mix event and sat through these OData presentations.  It includes code samples for obtaining data via objective C or any other subscriber/device/language from an OData provider (including SQL Server).  They are well worth the watch if you're interested in data access technologies.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM10

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM11

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM16